# Row Header Value in Datagridview won't display

Tags: c#

I have the following code for assigning a value for each row header cell in my datagridview. However, this won't show in my output. Here's my code:

```
for (int i = 1; i < this.dataGrid.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(i + 6 + ":00 AM - " + i + 7 + ":00 AM");
            this.dataGrid.Rows[i].HeaderCell.Value = i .toString();
        }
    MessageBox.Show(this.dataGrid.Rows[4].HeaderCell.Displayed.ToString());
```

datagridview.HeaderCell.Displayed returns false. How do I change it? Thanks.

Comment: Your code works just fine, except for the typo. Make sure you have set RowHeaders.Visible = true; !

Comment: RowHeaders are visible, but the values assigned to it are not. The headers gets the values but don't display it.

Comment: There must be something alse going on. The code is fine! Do you see the headers without the values or are the headers invisible? Are they even headers of just the 1st column? They also should have a reasonable RowHeadersWidth, of course.

Comment: hi @TaW. The headers are visible without values. RowHeadersWidth are properly assigned to. I have realized that this problem occurs when I am using DataTable as the source of my datagridview values.

Answer (score 1):

Setting EnableHeadersVisualStyles property of datagrid to false should work.

```
this.dataGrid.EnableHeadersVisualStyles = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

See here : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumnheadercell(v=vs.110).aspx

> `Displayed` : Gets a value that indicates whether the cell is currently
>   displayed on-screen.(Inherited from DataGridViewHeaderCell.)

Try with `MessageBox.Show(this.dataGrid.Rows[4].HeaderCell.Value.ToString());`